# TypeScript's type inference for constructor parameters - I thought this would work?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

You can use the following code at the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to verify it.

Given this code:

```
class Alpha {

        private beta;

        constructor(b: Beta) {
                this.beta = b;
        }

        doSomething() {
                this.beta.doesNotExist();
        }

}

class Beta {

}
```

I kinda expected the compiler error `Property 'doesNotExist' does not exist on type 'Beta'.`.

But you only get that if you put the type on`beta` such as:

```
private beta:Beta;
```

I thought TypeScript had type inference for parameter assignments. For example, the parameter `b` is of type `Beta`. That you can verify if you add this to the constructor:

```
const test:string = beta;
```

and then you get the compiler error `Type 'Beta' is not assignable to type 'string'.`.

So my question is, why doesn't `private beta` be of type `beta`?

Or is this just something I need to learn and always put types on all private constructor members?

Comment: Shouldn't the constructor say `this.beta = b;`? Anyway, TS cannot do this kind of inference. `beta` is of type `any`. The assignment in the constructor "widens" the type of `b` (`Beta`) to `any`. Since `beta` is of type `any`, any property is valid. The easiest solution is to change the constructor parameter to say `constructor(private b: Beta)`, and remove the separate declaration of the `beta` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought TypeScript had type inference for parameter assignments

Nope.

## Fix

There are actually two:

### Annotate the member explicitly

```
class Alpha {

        private beta: Beta; // annotate

        constructor(b: Beta) {
                this.beta = b;
        }

        doSomething() {
                this.beta.doesNotExist();
        }

}

class Beta {

}
```

### Combine the parameter and the member declaration (better)

```
class Alpha {
        constructor(private beta: Beta) { // notice `private`
        }

        doSomething() {
                this.beta.doesNotExist();
        }

}

class Beta {

}
```

## More

Some notes on inference : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-inference.html

Comment: Wow, you can do `constructor(private beta: Beta)`?? Wow, I didn't know TypeScript supported that.

Nothing is mentioned at http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html - Where did you learn this trick?